# How to solve this recursion?

Tags: recurrence-relations

If $r>0$ holds and recursion is given by $T(r)=\alpha T(r^{1/\alpha})+\alpha r^{1/\alpha}$ where $\alpha\geq 2$ is fixed and assume $T(r)=O(1)$ for $r\leq1$.

What is $T(r)$?

Comment: Mmmm since it is a recurrence relation we can suppose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ right ? But $N^{1/\alpha}$ will hardly be an integer, especially if you iterate this "alpha-root" many times.

Comment: I might call that a functional equation, not a recursion. But you should be able to write a recursion equation for $T(N^{1/\alpha^n})$ as a function of $n$. Solve that first, then try to patch the solutions for different $N$ together. Is $T$ assumed to be continuous?

Comment: @zubzub I never said $N\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen assume $N>0$ and $T$ continuous

Comment: I'm might be wrong but I think we should be careful when if we consider $N \geq 1$ because "alpha-rooting" a number many times will make it go to $1$ and the first part of the equation will tend to $\alpha$ and repeat itself infinitely many times since we don't have a bottom-recursion condition.

Comment: Continuity will help. While it is not technically *wrong* to use $N$ for a real variable, convention dictates that you avoid such usage. Most readers will assume it to be an integer.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen $N\rightarrow r$ made

Answer (score 0):

I've got a feeling that evaluating $T(N)$ at $N = 1$, then proceeds to express $T(N)$ as a summation of $\alpha ^k . N^\frac{1}{\alpha ^{k+1}}$ and $\alpha . T(N^\frac{1}{\alpha ^{n+2}})$ where $n$ is the number of terms, then taking limit to infinity will help

Comment: Yes, but that summation is not easy (as I found out after my first comment on the question).